# Switching to CloudObject`Private`

Tags: plotting, bugs, predictive-interface

I shut Mathematica done, then restart it. The image shows all that I do. I have done nothing else. Can anyone explain what is happening to me?

[image]

The complete code is:

```
x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
y[t_] := t^3 + 5;

Manipulate[Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}],
{{fcn, x, "Graph Type"}, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}}]
```

P.S. This is also after contacting Wolfram support who suggested that I uninstall Mathematica, download again, and reinstall.

Comment: Is WRI suggestion the solution?

Comment: @Kuba: Can you tell me what WRI means? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spurious context change is a bug and can be avoided by [turning the Suggestions Bar off](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/121).

The predictive interface tries a number of evaluations behind the scenes, each wrapped in `TimeConstrained` so they don't take too long. Depending on the input, some of these predictions may end up using (and autoloading) other functionality. The context path corruption can happen when this package loading process gets interrupted in the middle.

Comment: This worked. Wolfram Support also called me this morning and I shared this code and your comment about turning the Suggestions Bar off  with them. The advisor on the  phone said "Yes, we also make that suggestion."