# Unexpected context change

Tags: evaluation, symbolic, contexts, predictive-interface

I have a strange problem with Mathematica (`10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)`). Namely when I evaluate expression

```
assumptions = {0 < t1 < t2, 0 < t3}
```

the context is automatically switched to

```
Parallel`Concurrency`Private `
```

or just

```
Parallel`
```

Before:

```
In[1] $Context
      $ContextPath

Out[1] "Global`"
Out[2] {"PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"}
```

After:

```
In[1] $Context
      $ContextPath

Out[1] "Parallel`"
Out[2] {"Parallel`VirtualShared`", "Parallel`Status`", 
        "Parallel`Palette`","Parallel`Parallel`", "Parallel`Kernels`",
        "Parallel`Protected`", "Parallel`Developer`", "Parallel`", "System`"}
```

Does anybody has any explanation for this behavior? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I don't have 10.1 installed anymore, but I would try turning off the suggestions bar (and perhaps restarting the front end).

Comment: This problem is similar to [84515](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84515/switching-to-cloudobjectprivate), I think it has been improved in later versions.

Comment: @Szabolcs It's my work computer. I'll try tomorrow and update. As a matter of fact, it all started when I changed context to notebook (via menu). Though I reversed the context back to global, the problem persisted and actually it extended to any notebook persisting over sessions.

Comment: @Szabolcs In light of these new findings, should this be marked as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @ilian, the problem was somehow miraculously caused by the Suggestion bar. Turning Suggestion bar off, as suggested by @Mr.Wizard in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/34848) resolved the issue.